# Java Socks5 client and UDP support with Dante server

Tags: java, android, sockets, proxy, udp

I am writing SOCKS5 client

Ive got autorization and udp associate ready over TCP

Ive got address and port of the relay server but i am missing something with udp transmition...

```
   clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
   IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName(serverHostname); 

   byte[] sendData = new byte[1024]; 
   byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024]; 

   String sentence = "xxx"; 
   sendData = sentence.getBytes();                             

   DatagramPacket sendPacket =  new DatagramPacket(
                                     sendData, 
                                     sendData.length, 
                                     IPAddress, 
                                     sCon.getDstPort()); 

   byte[] addr = sendPacket.getAddress().getAddress();

   byte[]head = new byte[6+addr.length];
   head[0] = (byte) 0x00; //RSV
   head[1] = (byte) 0x00; //RSV
   head[2] = (byte) 0x00; //frag
   head[3] = (byte) 0x01; //Address type
   //Put Address
   System.arraycopy(addr,0,head,4,addr.length);      
   //Put port
   head[head.length - 2] = (byte) (sendPacket.getPort() >> 8);
   head[head.length - 1] = (byte) (sendPacket.getPort());                              


   byte[] buf = new byte[head.length + sendPacket.getLength()];
   byte[] data = sendPacket.getData();
   //Merge 
   System.arraycopy(head,0,buf,0,head.length);
   System.arraycopy(data,0,buf,head.length,sendPacket.getLength());

   DatagramPacket updated = new DatagramPacket(
                                     buf,
                                     buf.length,
                                     relayAddr,
                                     relayPort);                               
   clientSocket.send(updated);
```

Socks5 srever -> 192.168.11.52

serverHostname -> 192.168.11.39

client IP -> 192.168.11.49

Example situation

```
Target /192.168.11.39, port 9876
SOCKS5 RelayAddr /192.168.11.52, RelayPort 56945
```

Dante log

```
block(0): udp: expected from 192.168.11.39.148, got it from 192.168.11.49.59124
```

Every time there is 192.168.11.39**.148** and i dont understand where is something wrong.
DatagramPacket never reaches the destination host

Comment: Curious. The fifth number is the local port assigned to the socket on the local machine of your SOCKS5 server, I remember having messing with Dante and logs were a bit abstract sometimes, but maybe what it's telling you that what he was expecting on port 59124 was received on port 148, so is it possible you're opening more than one socket at a time?

Comment: no, only one. 39 is a target host, 49 is client so this are source ports. Sock5 rfc is talking about destination ports only, nothing about source.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, sorry for the confusing explaination. I meant the 'local machine of the server', so the remote :-) I will think about it and if I get some idea I'll write.

Comment: ive found the problem.

rfc:
          o  DST.ADDR       desired destination address
          o  DST.PORT desired destination port in network octet
             order
ive misunderstud that, DST.ADDR and DST.PORT are about the client not the target